# How to disable balloon popups/tooltips ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I have this annoying balloon window that pops up when I try to copy a link from anywhere on my computer. I'm not quite sure if this is a ubuntu issue or a cinnamon desktop one. Id like to know how to disable it and a couple of others. Id rather not disable all balloon popups because they are nice for figuring out what GIMP tools do what, but if I have to disable all of them all to get rid of these that is expectable.

[image: annoying balloon/tooltips: firefox open with]

[image: annoying balloon/tooltips: colorpicker]

Comment: Does this afflict any one else? Am I the only one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popup/balloon window that pops up when I was trying to select links is caused by Cairo Dock. Not really an Ubuntu problem. It is caused by the Clipboard History add-on.

To get rid of it you can select Advanced Mode (at the bottom of the settings window) and scroll down to Accessories and select Clipboard History. Move to the Configuration tab. At the top right there is a drop down menu change it from [Selection] to [Clipboard]. Also scroll down to Actions and disable everything in Actions. Popup is now gone.

Cant figure out exactly how to get rid of the other tooltip/popup yet but I will get that sorted as well and update this answer.